# I am found this type of result where User_id and full_name print everytime. full_name print one time and related multiple data shows in a single array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

```
$nearProviderdata = DB::table('users','category')
            ->leftJoin('service_provider_rating', 'users.id', '=', 'service_provider_rating.rating_receiver_user_id')
            ->leftJoin('service_provider_category', 'users.id', '=', 'service_provider_category.user_id')
            ->leftJoin('category', 'category.id', '=', 'service_provider_category.category_id')
            ->select('users.id as user_id','users.full_name','category.id as category_id','category.title')
            ->distinct()->get()->groupBy('user_id');
```

I am receiving the below response from the above code.

```
[0] => stdClass Object
  (
    [user_id] => 11
    [full_name] => Jimmi Patel
    [category_id] => 1
    [title] => Painter
  )

 [1] => stdClass Object
 (
   [user_id] => 11
   [full_name] => Jimmi Patel
   [category_id] => 2
   [title] => Home Cleaner
  )

  [2] => stdClass Object
  (
    [user_id] => 11
    [full_name] => Jimmi Patel
    [category_id] => 3
    [title] => Electrician
   )
```

I want the result something like as below

```
[0] => stdClass Object
  (
    [user_id] => 11
    [full_name] => Jimmi Patel
    ['category'] => [ category_id => 1,title => Painter, category_id => 2, title => Home Cleaner, category_id => 3, title => Electrician]
   )
```

It's laravel version 5.7. I have tried group by also to get the result but it is showing only 1 row and 1 category data. So i am using the subquery to get the data. Please let me know if i am doing something wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to join that much with raw query
better use models for this purpose

Simplified example:

```
   $nearProviderdata = User::with(
        'categories', 
        'serviceProviderRating',
        'serviceProviderCategory'
)->get();
```

You can also add select in subquery and map response